# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected when going from "/login" to "/home" via a navigation guard

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, dashboard

I am working on an admin dashboard template ( Vuexy Vue + Laravel template ) and am facing an issue with the login component, while I sign in successfully, I don't get redirected to the home page. I am getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected when going from "/login" to
> "/home" via a navigation guard.

Here's the code for the **Login component**:

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable global-require */
import { ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver } from 'vee-validate'
import VuexyLogo from '@core/layouts/components/Logo.vue'
import {
  BRow,
  BCol,
  BLink,
  BFormGroup,
  BFormInput,
  BInputGroupAppend,
  BInputGroup,
  BFormCheckbox,
  BCardText,
  BCardTitle,
  BImg,
  BForm,
  BButton,
  BAlert,
  VBTooltip,
  BTabs,
  BTab,
} from 'bootstrap-vue'
import useJwt from '@/auth/jwt/useJwt'
import { required, email } from '@validations'
import { togglePasswordVisibility } from '@core/mixins/ui/forms'
import store from '@/store/index'
import { getHomeRouteForLoggedInUser } from '@/auth/utils'

import ToastificationContent from '@core/components/toastification/ToastificationContent.vue'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  directives: {
    'b-tooltip': VBTooltip,
  },
  components: {
    BTabs,
    BTab,
    BRow,
    BCol,
    BLink,
    BFormGroup,
    BFormInput,
    BInputGroupAppend,
    BInputGroup,
    BFormCheckbox,
    BCardText,
    BCardTitle,
    BImg,
    BForm,
    BButton,
    BAlert,
    VuexyLogo,
    ValidationProvider,
    ValidationObserver,
  },
  mixins: [togglePasswordVisibility],
  data() {
    return {
      status: '',
      password: 'Vidur@123',
      userEmail: 'admin@vidur.ml',
      sideImg: require('@/assets/images/pages/staff.svg'),

      formsData: {
        type: 'Staff',
      },
      responseData: {},

      // validation rules
      required,
      email,
      tabData: [
        { home: 'Candy canes donut chupa chups candy canes lemon drops oat cake wafer. Cotton candy candy canes marzipan carrot cake. Sesame snaps lemon drops candy marzipan donut brownie tootsie roll. Icing croissant bonbon biscuit gummi bears. Pastry gummi bears sweet roll candy canes topping ice cream. Candy canes fruitcake cookie carrot cake pastry.' },
        { profile: 'Carrot cake dragée chocolate. Lemon drops ice cream wafer gummies dragée. Chocolate bar liquorice cheesecake cookie chupa chups marshmallow oat cake biscuit. Dessert toffee fruitcake ice cream powder tootsie roll cake.Pudding candy canes sugar plum cookie chocolate cake powder croissant.' },
        { disabled: 'lorem' },
        { about: 'Carrot cake dragée chocolate. Lemon drops ice cream wafer gummies dragée. Chocolate bar liquorice cheesecake cookie chupa chups marshmallow oat cake biscuit. Dessert toffee fruitcake ice cream powder tootsie roll cake.Carrot cake dragée chocolate. Lemon drops ice cream wafer gummies dragée. Chocolate bar liquorice cheesecake cookie chupa chups marshmallow oat cake biscuit.' },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    passwordToggleIcon() {
      return this.passwordFieldType === 'password' ? 'EyeIcon' : 'EyeOffIcon'
    },
    imgUrl() {

      if (this.formsData.type == 'staff') {
        this.sideImg = require('@/assets/images/pages/staff.svg')
      } else if (this.formsData.type == 'doctor') {
        this.sideImg = require('@/assets/images/pages/doctor.svg')
      } else if (this.formsData.type == 'admin') {
        this.sideImg = require('@/assets/images/pages/admin.svg')
      }
      return this.sideImg
    },
  },
  methods: {
    mode(mo) {
      this.formsData.type = mo;
    },
    login() {
      this.$refs.loginForm.validate().then(success => {
        if (success) {
          // useJwt
          //   .login({
          //     email: this.userEmail,
          //     password: this.password,
          //   })
          this.$http.post('/api/login',{
              email: this.userEmail,
              password: this.password,
              category: this.formsData.type,
              manager: 'no',

            })
            
            .then(response => {
              // const { userData } = response.data
              this.responseData = response
              this.responseData = this.responseData.data.results
              console.log(this.responseData)
              localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData))
              localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(this.responseData.token))
               
              this.$router.replace(getHomeRouteForLoggedInUser(this.responseData.role)).then(() => {
                this.$toast({
                  component: ToastificationContent,
                  position: 'top-right',
                  props: {
                    title: `Welcome ${this.responseData.fullName || this.responseData.username}`,
                    icon: 'CoffeeIcon',
                    variant: 'success',
                    text: `You have successfully logged in as ${this.responseData.role}. Now you can start to explore!`,
                  },
                })
              })
            })
            .catch(error => {
              this.$refs.loginForm.setErrors(error.response.data.error)
            })
        }
      })
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

( Only the js part included )

The **getHomeRouteForLoggedInUser** is imported from an auth **Utils** file

```
import useJwt from '@/auth/jwt/useJwt'

/**
 * Return if user is logged in
 * This is completely up to you and how you want to store the token in your frontend application
 * e.g. If you are using cookies to store the application please update this function
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line arrow-body-style
export const isUserLoggedIn = () => {
  return localStorage.getItem('userData') && localStorage.getItem(useJwt.jwtConfig.storageTokenKeyName)
}

export const getUserData = () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'))


export const getHomeRouteForLoggedInUser = userRole => {
  if (userRole === 'admin') return '/'
  return { name: 'auth-login' }
}
```

This is the main **route** file code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

// Routes
import { canNavigate } from '@/libs/acl/routeProtection'
import { isUserLoggedIn, getUserData, getHomeRouteForLoggedInUser } from '@/auth/utils'
import apps from './routes/apps'
import dashboard from './routes/dashboard'
import uiElements from './routes/ui-elements/index'
import pages from './routes/pages'
import chartsMaps from './routes/charts-maps'
import formsTable from './routes/forms-tables'
import others from './routes/others'
import polo from './routes/polo'
import home from './routes/home'
import vid from './routes/vid'
import homeDialysis from './routes/home-dialysis'
import axios from 'axios'

import staffHome from './routes/staff/staffHome'
import staffBranch from './routes/staff/staffBranch'
import patientBill from './routes/staff/patientBill'
import staffAppointments from './routes/staff/staffAppointments'
import staffBloodReport from './routes/staff/staffBloodReport'
import patientSessionSheet from './routes/staff/patientSessionSheet'
import patient from './routes/staff/patient'
import currentlyDialysing from './routes/staff/currentlyDialysing'
import staffHomeDialysis from './routes/staff/staffHomeDialysis'
import staffManagePatient from './routes/staff/staffManagePatient'
import staffOfflineRecord from './routes/staff/staffOfflineRecord'
import staffTelemedicine from './routes/staff/staffTelemedicine'

import doctorHome from './routes/doctor/doctorHome'
import doctorDailyReport from './routes/doctor/doctorDailyReport'
import doctorPrescription from './routes/doctor/doctorPrescription'
import doctorReport from './routes/doctor/doctorReport'
import doctorDialysisData from './routes/doctor/doctorDialysisData'
import graphsStatistics from './routes/doctor/graphsStatistics'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  },
  routes: [
    { path: '/', redirect: { name: 'home' } },
    ...apps,
    ...dashboard,
    ...pages,
    ...chartsMaps,
    ...formsTable,
    ...uiElements,
    ...others,
    ...polo,
    ...home,
    ...vid,
    ...homeDialysis,
    ...staffHome,
    ...staffBranch,
    ...patientBill,
    ...staffAppointments,
    ...staffBloodReport,
    ...patientSessionSheet,
    ...patient,
    ...currentlyDialysing,
    ...staffHomeDialysis,
    ...staffManagePatient,
    ...staffOfflineRecord,
    ...staffTelemedicine,
    ...doctorHome,
    ...doctorDailyReport,
    ...doctorPrescription,
    ...doctorReport,
    ...doctorDialysisData,
    ...graphsStatistics,
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: 'error-404',
    },
  ],
})

router.beforeEach((to, _, next) => {
  const isLoggedIn = isUserLoggedIn()

  if (!canNavigate(to)) {
    // Redirect to login if not logged in
    // if (!isLoggedIn) return next({ name: 'auth-login' })
    if (!isLoggedIn) return next({ name: 'auth-login' })

    // If logged in => not authorized
    return next({ name: 'misc-not-authorized' })
  }

  // Redirect if logged in
  if (to.meta.redirectIfLoggedIn && isLoggedIn) {
    const userData = getUserData()
    router.push(getHomeRouteForLoggedInUser(userData ? userData.role : null))
  }
  // axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')}})
  // .then(res => console.log(res))
  // .catch(err => console.log(err))

  return next()
})

// ? For splash screen
router.afterEach(() => {
  const appLoading = document.getElementById('loading-bg')
  if (appLoading) {
    appLoading.style.display = 'none'
  }
})

export default router
```

I am stuck at this issue for so long and haven't been able to find any working solution. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error occur to me: My problem was that my userData hasn't been saved into localStorage at the time of my router trying to access it.

Vue router is complaining here that you're somehow instantly redirected back to the page you're starting from. Most likely due to a faulty authorization workflow. (see [here](https://newbedev.com/vue-router-uncaught-in-promise-error-redirected-from-login-to-via-a-navigation-guard))

I'd suggest you to investigate around your `isUserLoggedIn()`-method as well as your `router.beforeEach`.

Also maybe try to use Vuex for your auth handling. Here's a great tutorial for that: https://dev.to/romanpaprotsky/vue-js-token-based-authentication-with-laravel-sanctum-3a84